# rviz blank with ATI graphic card

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running RViz on ROS Indigo and just by doing `rosrun rviz rviz` the display is blank, showing no data (not even the grid). I know it works because I can click and drag, the topics such as 2D Nav Goal work or I can see the view changing. If I resize the rviz window then the blank screen looks weird (deformed vision and lines from the previous background). I have seen other similar issues on VM machines but the issues didn't fix my case.

Some more data: I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad E550 with Radeon R7 M260 graphics card, using the default Ubuntu 14.04.05 drivers (because if I install others it will not work).

[ INFO] [1478886940.755808950]: rviz version 1.11.15
[ INFO] [1478886940.755870091]: compiled against Qt version 4.8.6
[ INFO] [1478886940.755884163]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [1478886940.856285919]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1478886940.856367826]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).

Any advice or recommendation?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247901/rviz-blank-with-ati-graphic-card/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that I was able to fix it by running [1]:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic`

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`

However I am not entirely sure if this was the only thing, as I also run previously [2]:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

References:
[1](http://askubuntu.com/a/643144)
[2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20589728)

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-11-11**:
Typical case in which I was looking for the answer for about 2 hours, I decide to post and then I find it in 5 minutes...